# Is there any way to create an STL map with a composite key and a composite value?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to create a map, something like: `[{11,"Jitendra", 15.5}, {12, "Pranay", 15.5}]`, where the data between first curly brackets becomes the *key* and between the second curly brackets becomes *values*. Whatever technique I am trying it results in error.

Please let me know how I can declare an STL map, insert and manipulate values?

Comment: What does `{11,"Jitendra", 15.5}` represent?  Turn that into a class and use that as the key and value type of your map.

Comment: my main intention is map should contain key with more than or equal to 2 elements and values same way

Answer (score 1):

Compound variables are usable as keys for a map as long as they are comparable with `operator<` (see [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)). The simplest case is using a `std::pair`:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, std::string>, int> mymap; // key: int, string; value: int
```

You can extend the concept with an arbitrary number of key elements by using [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) as introduced in C++11.

Both pairs and tuples bring their own comparator overloads (see e.g. for tuple [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp)), so no further work is needed on your side if your tuple elements are comparable by-themselves and are happy with an ordering that gives precedence on the first, then the second, and so on, element of the pair/tuple. Use `std::make_pair()` or `std::make_tuple()` to conveniently create them. However, it also works like this (C++17):

```
std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::tuple<int, int>> foo;
// insert
foo[{1,2}] = {3,4};

// access
auto [v1, v2] = foo[{1,2}];
std::cout << v1 << ", " << v2 << std::endl;
```

To be most flexible, you can extend it even further by using a `struct` and providing a comparator for the map to order its elements. You can also do this if your compiler lives behind the moon and does not support C++11.

Comment: Dear friends, thanks for answering. Now I understand the concept and explore more. Earlier I was not aware about this fix with overloading < or using tuple. Thanks everyone for their valuable comment.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you might want to accept it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers